# Angular subscribe using defined function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is rather simple but I haven't seen it asked yet so; I am using a service like this:

```
this.comService.currentMembers.subscribe(members => this.sortMembers(members));
```

and I have sortMembers defined below (no need to read it, just for reference):

```
sortMembers(members: IProfile[]): void {
    this.members = members.slice().sort((profile1, profile2) => {
        if (profile1.name > profile2.name)
            return 1;
        if (profile1.name < profile2.name)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Is the inline function above, `members => this.sortMembers(members)`, the correct way to call the function I have defined because `this.comService.currentMembers.subscribe(this.sortMembers);` does not work like I had expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct way. If you use the format `this.comService.currentMembers.subscribe(this.sortMembers);` you are simply passing the reference to a function and it will have no `this` reference which I'm assuming was the problem you were running into. You can get around this by binding the `this` reference tho (but your first format is probably the best to use): `this.comService.currentMembers.subscribe(this.sortMembers.bind(this));`

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. Another way, if you want to use like `this.comService.currentMembers.subscribe(this.sortMembers);`

You can change method to [`instance arrow function`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions) to preserve `this`:

```
sortMembers = (members: IProfile[]) => {
    this.members = members.slice().sort((profile1, profile2) => {
        if (profile1.name > profile2.name)
            return 1;
        if (profile1.name < profile2.name)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

This approach has **pros and cons**. As @Daniel W Strimpel said above:

> but your first format is probably the best to use

to avoid side effects